# Get the RadioButton titlelabel.text value in UITableView Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, xcode9

Loading dynamic data in UITableView. I have 2 `RadioButtons(groupButtons)` with `btnPaul` and `btnAdam` title Paul and Adam in `UITableView` and a `label(lblCheckStatus)`. if `[cell.btnPaul setSelected:YES];` the `btnPaul.titlelebel.text` should assing to label i.e., Paul and if `[cell.btnPaul setSelected:NO];` label should be empty in `UITableView`. The followign code is i have tried, but could not get the correct response getting null value. TIA

```
// cellForRowAtIndexPath:

NSMutableDictionary* respDict = [respnseArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSString *str = [respDict objectForKey:@"Name"];

if ([str isEqualToString:@"Paul"]) {
    [cell.btnPaul setSelected:YES];
} else {
    [cell.btnAdam setSelected:YES];
}

cell.btnPaul.tag = +indexPath.row;
[cell.btnPaul addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCheckClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

cell.btnPaul.tag = +indexPath.row;
[cell.btnPaul addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCheckClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

// RadioButton Checked
- (IBAction)btnCheckClicked:(RadioButton *)sender {

    UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
    NSUInteger tag = btn.tag;

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    FriendsCell *cell = (FriendsCell *) [_btlFriends dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.lblCheckStatus.text = sender.titleLabel.text;

    NSLog(@"%@",cell.lblCheckStatus.text);
}
```

Comment: why you add `= +indexPath.row;`

Answer (score 0):

First, remove `+` when setting radio button tag.

```
cell.btnPaul.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.btnPaul addTarget:self action:@selector(btnCheckClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Then use the tag for getting indexPath. When you the indexPath then you can access then cell also the cell component. Hope this will help you.

```
- (IBAction)btnCheckClicked:(RadioButton *)sender {

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[sender tag] inSection:0];
    FriendsCell *cell = [_btlFriends cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.lblCheckStatus.text = cell.btnPaul.titleLabel.text;

    NSLog(@"%@",cell.lblCheckStatus.text);
}
```